# JXA: display dialog with custom icon

Tags: javascript, applescript, javascript-automation

With AppleScript, we can easily display a dialog with a custom icon:

```
display dialog "Test" with icon POSIX file "{{path_to_our_icon}}"
```

How can we do the same with JXA (JavaScript for Automation)? The [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayDialogsandAlerts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH15-SW1) doesn’t seem to cover this. It only tells us how to use one of the predefined icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where the SDEF dictionary specifies an argument of type *file* you need a full path string wrapped in the Path() constructor.

(For more on Path() see under 'Paths' in the JavaScript for Automation Release Notes)

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var a = Application.currentApplication(),
        sa = (a.includeStandardAdditions = true, a);

    sa.displayDialog('Test', {
        defaultAnswer: 'Next question ?',
        buttons: ['OK', 'Cancel'],
        defaultButton: 'OK',
        cancelButton: 'Cancel',
        withTitle: 'Test dialog',
        withIcon: Path('/System/Library/Frameworks/Automator.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Automator.icns')
    });
})();
```